# Who discovered the Virial Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, thermodynamics, energy

Who first discovered the Virial Theorem? Who first wrote it down? When? Where?

<sup>My guess: a 19<sup>th</sup> century thermodynamicist</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [*OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/223773), Clausius coined the German word "virial" (from *vīs* force, strength):

> a. In Clausius' kinetic theorem of gases: (see quots.). ***virial theorem***, the theorem that for a steady-state system of particles obeying an inverse square law of force, the time-average of the kinetic energy equals the time-average of the virial; or equivalently, that the potential energy is twice the total energy and the kinetic energy is the negative of the total energy.

See:

- R. Clausius, “[XVI. On a Mechanical Theorem Applicable to Heat](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/XZVZN9VN/Clausius%20-%201870%20-%20XVI.%20On%20a%20mechanical%20theorem%20applicable%20to%20heat.pdf),” *The London, Edinburgh, and Dublin Philosophical Magazine and Journal of Science* 40, no. 265 (August 1870): 122–27.